# How to change Background Color of an element with Javascript and set it as IMPORTANT

Tags: javascript, background-color

I know by this code I can change the `color` of an element to something else and set it as `!important`:

```
document.getElementById("usernamestatus").style.setProperty('color', 'red', 'important');
```

But I don't know how to change the `background-color` of an element by using this syntax.

In fact I tried this but didn't change the background:

```
document.getElementById("usernamestatus").style.setProperty('backgroundColor', 'red', 'important');
```

So if you know, please let me know...

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `background-color` not `backgroundColor`:

```js
document.getElementById("usernamestatus").style.setProperty('background-color', 'red', 'important');
```

```css
#usernamestatus {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="usernamestatus"/>
```